# Full form of LEB in VIPer01 block diagram

Tags: mosfet, voltage-regulator, buck

[image: Block diagram of VIPer01]

How does LEB function and how does it operate in this block diagram?

Answer (score 0):

Leading edge blanking is used especially on current sense analog inputs where during the switching event, there will be some parasitics in your circuit, mainly stray inductance and semiconductor capacitance which can falsely trigger OCP. To remedy this, leading edge blanking is used to make for example OCP blind for a short while.

ST didn't include anything about it in the VIPer 01 datasheet from what I could find, but the concept is universal so here is an overview I borrowed from Microchip (https://onlinedocs.microchip.com/pr/GUID-0265987E-0E72-4A61-BC22-821E491C6E08-en-US-1/index.html?GUID-29D26453-A532-498D-9D94-5E3DDA5E386D)

[image]